# Docstring for toml file in Python

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, toml

Since 3.11, Python [tomblib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tomllib.html) provides support for TOML files.
I would like to know if there is a way to add docstrings to the fields in the TOML file.

In particular, to be rendered with Sphinx.
I am looking for something like [autoyaml](https://github.com/Jakski/sphinxcontrib-autoyaml).

Comment: TOML has comments, but no docstrings (in the Python sense) as far as I can tell (https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#comment).

Comment: If you want software recommendations ("something like autoyaml"), you should ask at [softwarerecs.se].